# Insert a Row after every instance of specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to insert a new blank row after every instance of HDR in the sheet. I cannot figure out how to make the code move beyond the first instance to continue through the rest of the sheet.

```
 Sub NewRowInsert()

    Dim SearchText As String
    Dim GCell As Range

    SearchText = "HDR"
    Set GCell = Cells.Find(SearchText).Offset(1)
    GCell.EntireRow.Insert

 End Sub
```

Comment: You're going to need a loop *somewhere*... Have you tried looking up things like "vba excel loop range"?

Comment: I've tried to loop it a few times either using For row = 2 To numRows
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) but I have not been successful

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve] - we can't know what you've tried and whether you've put any effort researching the problem if you don't include it in your post.

Comment: Why not include the code with the loop? Not working is why you are here and what we can help with. If you share the code and explain the problem.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the loop code initially, I just sent the part that had been working for at least one of the records. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a()         As Variant
Dim found       As Range
Dim fStr        As String
Dim fAdd        As String
Dim i           As Long

fStr = "HDR"
Set found = Cells.Find(What:=fStr, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not found Is Nothing Then
    fAdd = found.Address

    Do
        ReDim Preserve a(i)
        a(i) = found.Offset(1).Address
        i = i + 1
        Set found = Cells.FindNext(found)
    Loop Until found.Address = fAdd
End If

If i = 0 Then Exit Sub
For i = UBound(a) To LBound(a) Step -1
    Range(a(i)).EntireRow.Insert
Next i
End Sub
```

Another option

```
Sub Test()
Dim a()         As Variant
Dim oRange      As Range
Dim found       As Range
Dim fStr        As String
Dim fAdd        As String

fStr = "HDR"
Set found = Cells.Find(What:=fStr, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not found Is Nothing Then
    fAdd = found.Address

    Do
        If oRange Is Nothing Then Set oRange = found.Offset(1) Else Set oRange = Union(oRange, found.Offset(1))
        Set found = Cells.FindNext(found)
    Loop Until found.Address = fAdd
End If

If Not oRange Is Nothing Then oRange.EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: if possible avoid redim preserve, certainly within a loop. You can oversize at start, use a counter variable in the loop and resize the array at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added another option

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub NewRowInsert()

    Dim SearchText As String
    Dim GCell As Range
    Dim NumSearches As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    SearchText = "HDR"
    NumSearches = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells, SearchText)
    Set GCell = Cells(1, 1)

    For i = 1 To NumSearches

        Set GCell = Cells.Find(SearchText, After:=GCell, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Offset(1)
        GCell.EntireRow.Insert

    Next i


 End Sub
```